# Clustering algorithms assigning probability values

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining

I have a distance matrix for some data I want to cluster. However, I don't just want to assign elements to clusters, but I also want to assign a probability for each element to belong to each cluster.

Can you give me examples of clustering algorithms that can do that?

Is there, for instance, a hierarchical clustering algorithm that returns, for each element, a probability to belong to any cluster?

Comment: This question is very much like your previous one. Please merge them into one question.

Comment: check out Naive Bayes classifiers

Answer (score 1):

Learn about **fuzzy clustering**.

There is just so much more than plain old k-means...

Fuzzy algorithms assign non-binary cluster memberships, so it sounds like exactly what you are asking for. Again, this is not a single algorithm. This is a whole research subtopic.

Comment: I read about GraphLab bu do you recommend another library (preferably in python) for implementing fuzzy algorithms?